# Why doesn't MobX observables work with ternary operators?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Does anyone know why MobX observables can't re-render conditionally rendered components using the ternary operator? I'm using version 5 of MobX. To be clear, the first render works fine, `showComponent1` will be true and React will render `Component1`. But if you click the button to change `showComponent1` to false, no re-render will happen and it will still show `Component1` even though `showComponent` is false. This is shown in the example below.

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { observable } from "mobx";

@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  @observable
  showComponent1 = false;

  render() {
    return (
       <>
          {this.showComponent1 
             ? <Component1 />
             : <Component2 />
          }
          <button onClick={() => showComponent1 = true})>Show Component 2</button>
       </>
    )
  }
}
```

However, if I assign the observable to a variable with the render function, React will observe any changes to `showComponent1` observable and re-render the correct component. Does anyone know why this is happening and a better way of resolving this than re-assigning the observable?

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { observable } from "mobx";

@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  @observable
  showComponent1 = false;

  render() {
    const show1 = this.showComponent1;
    return (
       <>
          {show1
             ? <Component1 />
             : <Component2 />
          }
          <button onClick={() => showComponent1 = true})>Show Component 2</button>
       </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I just made a reproduction with your code, its works totally fine https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-72281165-vrrr3x (btw you forgot `this` in the onClick), could you make reproduction with your behaviour?

Comment: Yes, try this https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-72281165-forked-t5zceu?file=/src/App.js. I believe your code works because you made a reference to `this.showComponent1` in your onClick handler. If the only reference to the observable is with the ternary operator, it will not work

Comment: You code example works fine too (you forgot to change value to true in the handler, that's why Component2 always rendered)

Comment: Yeah you're right. It works on codesandbox but not on my local environment. It might be related to something else other than Mobx or React then